# Тег DIV в плагине syntax highlighter для CKEditor

Tags: php, ckeditor, wysiwyg, редактор, редактор-текста

Доброго дня...подскажите плиз по редактору CKEditor 4.0...есть проблемка пользуюсь плагином syntax highlighter для данного редактора...и при попытке добавления тега DIV внутрь кода HTML он почему-то не хочет оставаться там) нажимаю исходный код - а DIV уже за пределами

```
Привожу пример:
```

```
<pre class="brush:xml;">

<div class="krug_p">HOME</div>

</pre>
```

Так должно быть.Так и сохраняется. Но при повторном редактировании Div'ы почему-то выходят за пределы . Вот так

`<pre class="brush:xml;">



</pre>
<div class="krug_p">HOME</div>`

Answer (score 1):

< pre >< /pre > означена в HTML как контейнер для текста, возможно поэтому в "умном" редакторе блоки выносятся за рамки < pre >< /pre >. Если принципиально, попробуйте "обмануть" (было, помогало) - вместо < div >< /div > используйте < font >< /font >, например, с динамическим значением внутри

Comment: Самое интересное что это касается только div...все остальные теги остаются на своём месте внутри

Comment: Вообще уже столько наставил костылей чтоб нормально пользоваться этим ckeditor что уже воротит просто...может кто подскажет нормальный редактор для написания статей для сайта? Буду очень признателен)

Comment: Может стоит попробовать Markdown-разметку?

Comment: Почитаю...спасибо

Comment: почитал я про markdown...мой сайт написан на codeigniter...фреймворк такой если кто не знает...и даже нашёл библиотеку для него этого самого markdown...и даже поставил её в автозагрузку...а дальше что?нужно прикрутить новый markdown-редактор к текстовому полю, в котором пишу статьи? не совсем понимаю вообщем...поясните плиз неучу)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы...Видимо придётся мастерить очередной костыль